# Preserve Line Breaks - Input type="text"

Tags: html, input

I am working on a copy paste script, which works except that there are no line breaks in the paragraphs I am looking to copy. So, the outcome of pasting is displays all of the text on one line.

```
 <input type="text" value="This is the first line
 
 This is the second paragraph
 
 This is the third paragraph" id="myInput">
  <button onclick="myFunction(event)">Copy</button>
```

Example: When I copy this from the button, it pastes as:

This is the first line This is the second paragraph This is the third paragraph

Instead, I want the line to break in between paragraphs if possible

Comment: Have you tried adding `\n` on each line break? For eg: `This is the first line \n`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use textarea instead of input.

```
<textarea id="myInput">This is the first line
 
This is the second paragraph
 
This is the third paragraph</textarea>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead Use Textarea while inserting data and when you want to show use this function to preserve the line breaks echo nl2br($string);

For example

```
    <textarea class="form-control" name="short_desc" required></textarea>
```

and for frontend echo use following function

```
<?PHP echo nl2br($short_desc);?>
```

It will preserve the line break and show content with breaks on frontend,

also remember to keep the Mysql data type text for it.